# RSP1A sample rate vs if bandwidth

Tags: filters, downsampling, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, decimation

I'm using the RSP1A SDR and I want to understand how to choose the best configuration for receiving a signal of 125 khz bandwidth.

I would like to know if when choosing the option 200 KHz IF bandwidth with 2MSamples/s sample rate:

- we actually receive 2 Mhz of bandwidth and the remaining 900 Khz from both sides of the spectrum are attenuated

***OR***

- we only receive 200 khz of bandwidth sampled at 2 MSamples/s rate.

Since i want to reduce the sample rate of the captured signal,  i also would like to know if

- I only have to downsample (reduce the sample rate by a factor of N) since it is already filtered to a 200 Khz bandwidth

***OR***

- filter and then downsample as it is usually recommended to avoid aliasing.

Links to the RSP1A technical information : https://www.sdrplay.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/RSP1A-Technical-Information-R1P1.pdf and the RSP1A datasheet https://www.sdrplay.com/docs/171113RSP1AdatasheetV1.6.pdf

**EDIT for clarification :** 
As shown in the screenshot, for each sample rate (in this case I'm using the minimal allowed value : 2 MSamples/s), we can choose an IF bandwidth equal or less than the chosen sample rate value (so here i can choose between 1536, 600, 300 or 200 KHz).

[image]

Comment: When you refer to an option you can choose, what do you mean? Are you using software that has pre-selected configurations you need to choose from?

Comment: I'm referring to the options available when using the RSP1A API (which are also available when using the gnuradio block **RSP1A source** from the OOT module : **gr-sdrplay** https://gitlab.com/HB9FXQ/gr-sdrplay ). I'll edit the post and add a screenshot to show the available options .

Comment: So the option is not actually "IF Bandwidth" but just "Bandwidth". This could refer to the BPF in the front end, or in baseband. Are you sure which is it?

Comment: Well, I used "IF bandwidth" instead of just "bandwidth" because that's the term used by the SDRplay support in this forum discussion https://www.sdrplay.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4520&p=15888#p15888